# Is this sequence $\{\mu_n\}$ of probability measures weakly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Given $X=[a,b]$. Assume $\{\mu_n\}$ is a sequence of probability measures on $X$ such that for each polynomial $p\in\mathbf{R}[x]$, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{a}^{b}p\,\mathrm{d}\mu_n$$ exists. Then here is my **question:** is $\{\mu_n\}$ weakly convergent?

Here is my attempt: If $\{\mu_n\}$ is weakly convergent, then I have to show that there exists some probability measure $\mu$ such that $$\int_{a}^{b}f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_n\longrightarrow \int_{a}^{b}f\,\mathrm{d}\mu,\,\,\,\forall f\in C_b(X)$$ and here $C_b(X)=C(X)$ because $X$ is compact. By Stone–Weierstrass theorem we know for each $f\in C(X)$, there is a sequence of polynomials $\{p_m\}$ that converges to $f$ uniformly. Then I want to show $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{a}^b f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{a}^b \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}p_m\,\mathrm{d}\mu_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\int_{a}^b p_m\,\mathrm{d}\mu_n$$
exists. But I am **stuck** at here because I don't know what to do anymore. Could you give me some help/hints?

Answer (score 1):

By Helly's Selection Theorem any sequence of probability measures on the compact interval $X$ has  a weakly convergent subsequence. Let $\mu$ be the weak limit of such  a subsequence $(\mu_{n_k})$.

Given $f \in C(X)$ and $\epsilon >0$ choose a polynomial $p$ such that $|f(x)-p(x)| <\epsilon$ for all $x$. Then $|\int fd\mu_{n_k}-\int f d\mu|\leq |\int fd\mu_{n_k}-\int p d\mu_{n_k}|+\int pd\mu_{n_k}-\int p d\mu|+|\int p d\mu-\int f d\mu|$. Note that the first and the last terms do not exeed $\epsilon$ and the middle term tend to $0$ as $ k \to \infty$. This gives $|\int fd\mu_{n_k}-\int f d\mu|<3\epsilon$ for $k$ sufficiently large.

Now applying this to any subsequence of $(\mu_n)$ we that any subsequence of $(\mu_n)$ has  further subsequence converging weakly to $\mu$. [This requires the fact that $\mu$ does not vary with the subsequence. But if two probability measures give the same integral for any polynomial then they are equal]. It follows now that $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly.